# load different urls one by one after certain delay

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I have a array of urls which I want to load in the same browser window one by one. For now I am able to load a single url in a browser window using

```
window.location = url;
```

But when I put this window.location in a function and call that function infinitely in a loop with some delay the page just keeps on loading and nothing gets displayed. Code is below:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
    var urls = ["http://www.howstuffworks.com", "http://example.com"];
    var i = 0;
        function redirect_url(url)
        {
            window.location = url;
        }

        while (true)
        {
            setTimeout(function() { redirect_url(urls[i]); }, 5000);

            // update the index
            i = (i + 1) % urls.length;
        }

    </script>
</head>
```

What I want is when I open this script file in my browser then the first url's webpage should get loaded and after 5 secs second url's webpage should get loaded and this should continue infinitely.

Comment: I got the point why this code won't work as at each reload my script again tells browser to reload...though not found a solution yet

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a method without the While loop; Seems to work well on my end: http://jsfiddle.net/77617znz/2/

```
var urls = ["http://www.howstuffworks.com", "http://example.com"];
var i = 0;

function redirect_url()
{
    if( i <= urls.length )
    {
        setTimeout(function(){
            $('iframe').attr('src', urls[i]);
            i++;
            redirect_url();
        }, 3000);
    }
}

redirect_url();
```

Hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: I do enjoy a pretty recursive function. Looks good to me! Although maybe edit it so he is not iterating through his list backwards :)

Comment: @Kenji Thanks! I'll do that.

Comment: extra "=" in if

Comment: exactly what i was after..Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

`window.location = url;` will load the page with full refresh. Once that happens all the script from the previous page will not be available so what you are trying the achieve will never happen.

May be you can have an `iframe` on the page and change the iframe source every 5 seconds as you need.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(function () {
        var urls = ["http://www.howstuffworks.com", "http://example.com"];
        var i = 0;
        function loadIframe(url)
        {
            $('#iframe').attr('src', url);
        }

        setInterval(function() {
          // update the index
          i = (i + 1) % urls.length; 
          loadIframe(urls[i]); 
        }, 5000);

        loadIframe(urls[i]); 
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <iframe id="iframe" height="100%" width="100%"></iframe>

</body>
</html>
```

**Demo** http://plnkr.co/edit/hjx3b234MUDzkSL67RW5?p=preview

Comment: ohh got your point. Any Ideas how to achieve this. iframe seems good. can we load urls in iframe directly

Comment: setTimeout is asynchronous i guess that is why it is not working.Any other delay function in js which is synchronous.

Comment: this shouldn't work. it should hang your browser. the `while` loop never finishes and it keeps setting timeouts forever. its probably better to set the next timeout inside the handler (or use `setInterval`)

Comment: @yoavmatchulsky: thanks for pointing that out. I totally missed it.

Comment: @mSatyam: I have edited my answer to remove the while loop and used `setInterval` instead. Try it out.

Comment: @mSatyam: This solution is much better than the one you accepted.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think what you're trying to achieve can be done by the code you have posted.  If you set the location it will navigate to the new page and your JavaScript will cease to function.

You could try using some other systems such as IFRAMES or ajax requests to load and render them on your page.  This will lead to issues where the Origin of your page will not match the one you are loading. This will throw an error and the page will fail to load.

For the IFRAMEs the X-Frame-Options of the page you are loading will prevent it from being displayed.  Also if your page is HTTPS and the other page is not it will also fail to load.

Comment: yes yes...I am trying to do it with iframes now as suggested in below answers but those are not working yet.

Comment: The chances are that the pages you want to look at don't have the required headers set to allow you to display the page in an IFRAME.

IFRAMEs can be used for [clickjacking](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Clickjacking).  So unless the page allows it, it will not load in an IFRAME.

Comment: Just found that setTimeout works asynchronously that is why it is not working i guess.

Comment: Everything in JavaScript is async unless you specifically code for synchronous.

Comment: If you open in Chrome and use the developer tools you will see the error messages about the X-FRAME-OPTIONS

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on ShankarSangoli's answers since original code will not work. Looping through and doing the set timeout as 5000 will just load those urls simultaneously 5000 seconds from now. You need to increment that value.

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
var urls = ["http://www.howstuffworks.com", "http://example.com"];
var timeout = 5000;
    function loadIframe(url)
    {
        $('#iframe').attr('src', url);
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < urls.length; i++)
    {
        setTimeout(function() { loadIframe(urls[i]); }, timeout*i);
    }

</script>
```

```
<iframe id="iframe" height="100%" width="100%"></iframe>
```

Comment: this isn't working either, I think something asynchronous is making it not to work.

Comment: @mSatyam Yes, asynchronous is why you can not set a static value of 5000. Are you still seeing the same behavior? Can you provide a URL to where you are testing this at?

Comment: @mSatyam made some edits. Your infinite while may have been a problem. Should always use for loop if you are iterating like this. Ah... should have proofread my source code better. Shankars edits had issues as well :P