# iframe set src in loop only after one page is loaded

Tags: loops, iframe, synchronized, src

I am opening multiple pages in an iframe (one by one) i.e. i want to do it synchronously. So in a for loop i want to set iframe src property to url1 then once this page is loaded move to url2 and so on..

```
<iframe id="iframeExportPDF" onload="test();"></iframe>

$('#<%=Button1.ClientID%>').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var registrarIds = ($('#<%=lblRegistrarIdsForChart.ClientID%>').text()).split(',');

        for (var i = 0; i < registrarIds.length; i++) {
            var link = window.location.href;
            var urlBase = link.substring(0, link.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
            //alert(registrarIds[i].toString());
            ganttPopup(urlBase + 'GPS/CompetencyAssessment/GanttChart.aspx?id=' + registrarIds[i].toString(), registrarIds[i]);
            sleep(25000);
        }
    });

    function ganttPopup(url, id) {
    iframeExportPDF.src = url;
    //window.open(url, "_blank", "ganttChartPopup_" + id.toString(), "width=1100,height=600,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes");
}
```

P.S. Previously i was doing the same with opening multiple windows but since i have 1100 records, window.open would not be feasible.

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30784649/load-different-urls-one-by-one-after-certain-delay)

```
var urls = [], iCount;

$(function () {
    $('#<%=Button1.ClientID%>').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var registrarIds = ($('#<%=lblRegistrarIdsForChart.ClientID%>').text()).split(',');
        iCount = registrarIds.length;

        for (var i = 0; i < registrarIds.length; i++) {
            var link = window.location.href;
            var urlBase = link.substring(0, link.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
            var url = urlBase + 'GPS/CompetencyAssessment/GanttChart.aspx?id=' + registrarIds[i].toString();
            urls.push(url);
        }



        redirect_url();
   });

  function redirect_url() {
        if (iCount >= 0) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                $('#iframeExportPDF').attr('src', urls[iCount]);
                iCount--;
                redirect_url();
            }, 15000);
        }
    }
});
```